# 'Have you got home' or 'Are you back at home' or 'Are you at home now?'

Tags: question-words

Hi I'm just asking my girl friend if she's come back from the party. I want to ask get if she's at home now. Are the following sentences correct?

```
1-Have you got back home?
2-Are you back at home?
3-Are you at home now?
```

Comment: They are all correct. What makes you think one or more are not correct?